# _Layout styles not applied to Partial View rendered in a popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I am loading a partial view in the popup using following code:

```
<div id="Mydiv" title="Modify" class="ModifyRule" style="overflow: hidden" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //define config object
            var dialogOpts = {
                title: "Modify Rule",
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 700,
                open: function () {
                    //display correct dialog content
                    $("#Mydiv").load("Modify", { SelectedRow: $('#MyParam').val() });
                }
            };
            $("#Mydiv").dialog(dialogOpts);    //end dialog

            $('#Modify').click(
            function () {
                $("#Mydiv").dialog("open");
                return false;
            }
        );

        });


    </script>
```

Here is the code from partial view:

```
@Code

    Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @<div id="Master">
        <table>
                          <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.InputAuthorityGridDetail.TcmAccount)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.InputAuthorityGridDetail.TcmAccount)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.InputAuthorityGridDetail.Amount)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.InputAuthorityGridDetail.Amount)
                </td>
            </tr>
                          <tr align="right">
                <td>
                    <input name="button" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
             </div>    
    End Using

End Code
```

the controller method modify returns a partial view named _Modify, the view is rendered correctly in the popup but I notice that the CSS styles are not applied to the controls in the partial view can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post you code for the partial view?

Comment: Updated the question with partial view code

Comment: Where is the reference to use your css? And what location is your css stored in?

Comment: the reference to all my Css and js files is in _layout.vbhtml and the CSS and js are loaded in the main view correctly but they are not getting applied to the partialview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a partial is loaded into a layout page, the layout page contain the reference to the css that is used by the partial view.

However, from what I gather here (my javascript is not that great), you are loading the partial directly into a popup display and not using the layout page?  If this is correct then your partial will not know about the css.  And to correct this you would need to add a reference to the css at the top of the partial.

Comment: yes you are right I am loading the partial view directly in the popup. can you please give an example of how to add a reference of CSS and js files to partial view, I tried but it did not work

Comment: On second glance it appears that from the way you open the popup that it will never be processed server side and therefore you cannot use the razor syntax as it will never be processed.  Instead of using a partial you could use a html file with a reference to the css at the top.  Otherwise, my preference would be to open the partial differently with a call to a controller action so that it is processed with the layout, but i'm not sure how this call would be performed.  I hope though that you feel that I have answered your original question of why the css was not loaded.

Comment: @Parikshit major part of your question has been answered so accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

My partial views dont start with @Code and dont end with End Code. Try removing them and see if it works then.

Comment: Agreed.  And change the using(Html.BeginForm()) to @using(Html.BeginForm()) followed by braces { } to surround the form html, removing the End Using.